# Debug Assertion Failed Vector Subscript Out of Range C++

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I am using VS2015 C++. I tried reading a file and inputing it line by line into a vector using a while loop.

I get this error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
>
> File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector
>
> Line: 1234
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

My code is as follows:

```
int main() {
std::ifstream inf("walmart2.txt");

std::vector<std::string> blah;
int j = 0;

if (!inf) {
    std::cerr<< "Uh oh, walmart2.txt could not be opened for reading!" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
while (inf)
{
    std::string strInput;
    inf >> strInput;
    blah[j] = strInput;
    j = j + 1;
}

std::cout << blah.size() << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

The file "walmart2.txt" is around 1800 lines in the following format:

```
53.74
54.09
53.5
53.72
53.43
```

I'm not entirely sure whats going on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `blah[j] = strInput;` => `blah.push_back(strInput);`

Comment: Default-constructed vectors (like your `blah`) are *empty*. That means any indexing in them (even index `0`) will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> blah[j] = strInput;
> ```

This is **undefined behaviour** because `blah` is empty. Which means the compiler can make the program do anything.

When compiling with the right settings, Visual C++ makes use of that undefined behaviour in the C++ standard in order to actually detect the bug and show you this error message.

Fix the bug by using `push_back` instead:

```
blah.push_back(strInput);
```

Comment: Thanks...just a follow up...is it possible to convert the `strInput` from a string to a double? or is there a way to just read the line as a double instead of a string

Comment: @Migos: `std::stod`.

Comment: That is a different question. I suspect there are many duplicates for that at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing vector using index `blah[j] = strInput;` but vector is of zero size.

You can acheive your goal using

```
 blah.push_back(strInput);
```

And if you know the size int he starting then you can do something like this.

```
std::vector<std::string> blah(n); // Vector of size n will be declared
blah[j] = strInput; // 0 <= j < n
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) instead of operator[] to put value in your vector: `vec.push_back(input);`