# How can I fix an assertion failure that states 'vector subscript out of range'

Tags: c++

**Other questions that I viewed before posting this question:**

[Debug Assertion Failed: Vector subscript out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63236456/debug-assertion-failed-vector-subscript-out-of-range)

[Debug Assertion Failed Vector Subscript Out of Range C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333313/debug-assertion-failed-vector-subscript-out-of-range-c)

I am working on a Boids project, details of which can be found here:

https://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/

From what I can gather my issue is something to do with an index getting accessed by the function but no data is present in the index. I had this issue yesterday in a different area of my code and fixed it by making one of my getters return a reference rather than a copy of a class object. That approach seems to not be the issue today.

Below is my code:

This code is a snippet from my function that handles simulation events. This is the code that I have narrowed down the issue to.

```
//Remove flocking organisms with < 0 enery storage.
for (int i = 0; i < m_flock.getSize(); i++)
{
    if (m_flock.getOrganism(i).getEnergyStore() <= 0)
    {
        m_flock.removeOrganism(i);
        //m_notFlocking.flock.erase(m_notFlocking.flock.begin() + i);
        cout << "Organism died and has been removed..." << endl;
    }
}
```

The code below is from my Flock.cpp class definition file which details information on storing boids in a vector to then apply flocking behaviors to. This class function is giving the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7B87FC66 (ucrtbased.dll) in EvoSim.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

Code:

```
Organism &Flock::getOrganism(int i)
{
    return flock[i];
}
```

My suspicion is that the for loop size is not reflecting the recently erased object.

How can I fix the vector subscript error?

Edit:

This is the break point that shows up in the debugger:

```
    _NODISCARD _Ty& operator[](const size_type _Pos) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
#if _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0
        _STL_VERIFY(
            _Pos < static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst), "vector subscript out of range");
#endif // _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

        return _My_data._Myfirst[_Pos];
    }
```

Edit 2:

I did some messing around and discovered the issue only occurs when I run VS 2019 in debug mode, otherwise in Release mode it works fine and as expected.

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] so we can see the whole picture?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I assume I should use an iterator? Why will it skip?

Comment: @RetiredNinja im not sure how I can accomplish that with this considering its part of a really large project.

Comment: The process of narrowing down an isolated case to produce a [mcve] will often help you find the error yourself. A debugger is also useful in cases like this because you can trace through the code and see how you got there.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am using VS 2019. The debugger there suggested it was a value been passed to the getter. I assume that it is some out of range value or something.

Comment: @RemyLebeau very valid point. What is the solution to this. Do I decrement i each time an organism gets removed?

Comment: @Aeryes -- The better solution is to not write a loop, and instead use `std::remove_if`.

Comment: @Aeryes -- Is it important that you see the message printed to the screen for each erased item?  The reason being asked is that I am not sure if a simple `remove_if` will work in conjunction with showing the message (`std::partition` and then the erase will work).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no the message was only there for debugging purposes. I just wanted to see if the field for energy was getting changed.

Comment: *I did some messing around and discovered the issue only occurs when I run VS 2019 in debug mode, otherwise in Release mode it works fine and as expected.* -- It is not working fine in release mode.  The program is exhibiting undefined behavior in release, and the debug version is proof of this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I fixed the issue. It was coming from another area in the program as many here suspected. The reason why the issue occurred is because I had to vectors, one for the organisms object and another for the shape drawn to the screen. When I removed an organism from the first vector the shape still tried to draw in the render() function I have because the shapes position is tied to the organism objects position. I had to remove the shape from the shape vector also.

Comment: You can use the call stack in the debugger to see the sequence of code. So, crash in the getter, look up in the call stack and see where it was called from and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see nothing in this code that can cause an out of bounds access. However, you should not increment `i` on any loop iteration that removes an organism, otherwise you will skip the next organism in the list.

Imagine on the 1st loop iteration, the organism at index 0 needs to be removed. Subsequent organisms move down the list. On the next loop iteration, `i` gets incremented to 1, and the organism that had moved into index 0 is skipped.

Try this instead:

```cpp
//Remove flocking organisms with < 0 enery storage.
for (int i = 0; i < m_flock.getSize(); )
{
    if (m_flock.getOrganism(i).getEnergyStore() <= 0)
    {
        m_flock.removeOrganism(i);
        cout << "Organism died and has been removed..." << endl;
    }
    else
        ++i;
}
```

Alternatively, you can replace the entire loop using the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) via [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [`std::vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), eg:

```cpp
void Flock::removeDeadOrganisms()
{
    //Remove flocking organisms with < 0 enery storage.
    flock.erase(
        std::remove_if(flock.begin(), flock.end(),
          [](const auto &o){ return o.getEnergyStore() <= 0; }
        ),
        flock.end()
    );
}

...

m_flock.removeDeadOrganisms();
```

Or, in C++20, via [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2), eg:

```cpp
void Flock::removeDeadOrganisms()
{
    //Remove flocking organisms with < 0 enery storage.
    std::erase_if(flock,
        [](const auto &o){ return o.getEnergyStore() <= 0; }
    );
}
```

Comment: None of these fix the issue. I still get the vector subscript assertion issue.

Comment: @Aeryes then you need to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the same error. There is not enough context in what you have shown so far to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Aeryes -- How could there be an assertion about the subscript when the examples using `erase_if` do not use subscripts?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thats the part im confused about. When I comment out the segment of code that removes items everything works as expected. So I am unsure why nothing works.

Comment: Is this code part of a member function of a class?  If so, then maybe the instance of the class is invalid, and you're operating in an entirely invalid context.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this code is contained within a member function of a class. If the instance was invalid then surely the rest of the main simulation loop wouldnt work either?

Comment: @Aeryes -- No.  If the object is invalid, then the code exhibits undefined behavior.  There is no telling what could happen.  Also, admitting that this code is part of a class member function sheds an entirely different light on the issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how can I figure out if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

To loop though a vector that you are also modifying you don't want to `i++` on every loop, since if the element was removed you don't need to increment the index.  There are two solutions to this, either you can conditionally increment the index at the end of the loop or you can loop though the list backwards.

```cpp
int i = 0;
while (i < m_flock.getSize())
{
    if (m_flock.getOrganism(i).getEnergyStore() <= 0)
    {
        m_flock.removeOrganism(i);
        cout << "Organism died and has been removed..." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

```cpp
for (int i = m_flock.getSize(); i ; i--)
{
    if (m_flock.getOrganism(i).getEnergyStore() <= 0)
    {
        m_flock.removeOrganism(i);
        cout << "Organism died and has been removed..." << endl;
    }
}
```

You can't use a normal iterator loop for this because `vector::erase` ["Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).  However, you can use [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

```cpp
m_flock.erase(std::remove_if(m_flock.begin(),
                             m_flock.end(),
                             [](Organism org){
                                 return org.getEnergyStore()<=0;
                             }));
```

Comment: You *can* erase, the more or less [canonical](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) example would use `erase(std::remove_if(), end_iterator);`

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that.

Comment: I tried both of these examples and neither fixed the issue. I posted the breakpoint from the debugger in the edit at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @unDeadHerbs FYI, your `remove_if` predicate should take the `Organism` by reference, not by value.

Comment: @Aeryes what you describe is not possible with these examples, so there has to be another error in code you have not shown.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the issue is when I comment out the segment that removes items it all works just fine. The compiler only freaks out when I add code in to remove an organism. It says 'vector erase iterator outside of range'

Comment: @Aeryes Do you mean `m_flock.removeOrganism(i);` or the commented out line?

Comment: When I comment out the entire for loop and do nothing to remove the items. @unDeadHerbs

Comment: @Aeryes then you need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue in action. Clearly there is something else going on that we can't see yet.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I dont know how to reproduce this. All I can do is put the code up on github, which I plan to do once the project is completed anyways.

Comment: @Aeryes I will do you a favor:  [Take this code as-is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/786fc28699516c5a).  You see it works with no issues, given the answers you've received.  Now add to it until you duplicate the error you're claiming you are seeing.  Then go back to the question, and edit the post to show the issue.